# Removing empty strings from output of str_extract_all

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to tidy the output of `stringr::str_extract_all` so that any empty character elements are removed.

e.g. To extract the numbers from the following strings:

```
strings <- c("100 is 10 greater than 90", "1 in 10 people have 3 - 4 cats", "earth has 1 moon")

str_extract_all(strings, "\\d*")
```

This returns the answers, but lots of empty character elements

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "100" ""    ""    ""    ""    "10"  ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    "90"  ""   
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1"  ""   ""   ""   ""   "10" ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "3"  ""   ""   ""   "4"  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "1" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

How can I remove the `""` from this data whilst otherwise maintaining its structure? i.e.

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "100" "10" "90"   
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "1"  "10"   "3"   "4"   
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "1"
```

I tried some things along the lines of `str_extract_all(strings, "\\d*") %>% sapply(., "[!. == ""]")` but cannot get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct regex. Try

```
str_extract_all(strings, "\\d+")
#[[1]]
#[1] "100" "10"  "90" 
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "1"  "10" "3"  "4" 
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "1"
```

---

Another approach using `base R` only

```
numbers <- gregexpr("\\d+", strings)
regmatches(strings, numbers)
```

This could of course be written in one line as

```
regmatches(strings, gregexpr("\\d+", strings))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
lapply(str_extract_all(strings, "\\d*"), function(x) x[!x %in% ""])

[[1]]
[1] "100" "10"  "90" 

[[2]]
[1] "1"  "10" "3"  "4" 

[[3]]
[1] "1"
```

Or:

```
lapply(str_extract_all(strings, "\\d*"), function(x) x[nchar(x) >= 1])
```

Or:

```
lapply(str_extract_all(strings, "\\d*"), function(x) x[x != ""])
```

Or if you want to do it directly (by a slight modification of the code from @markus):

```
regmatches(strings, gregexpr("[0-9]+",  strings))
```